# Introspecting function names in a GHC module

Tags: haskell, reflection, ghc

Is there a way in the Glasgow Haskell Compiler to introspect the names of all functions in a module?

I am trying to create an automatic database migration system that, given the names of migration modules, introspects the names of the functions inside and calls them one at a time.

Something like

```
doMigrations("Migrations.M_2015")
doMigrations("Migrations.M_2016")
-- ...
```

where `Migration.M_2015` contains

```
module Migration.M_2015
where

migration_2015_01_02 :: DbConnection -> Status
migration_2015_01_02 connection =
    -- ...
```

Each `doMigration` will reflect the names of the migration functions in its module and only call those that have not been run before (names saved in a DB table). This will only be called at application start-up, so performance is not a big issue. The reflection can occur at either compile-time or run-time.

Comment: There is: It's called Template Haskell. It isn't terribly easy. A few Google searches should allow you to track down what little documentation exists for it.

Comment: Is there are reason you can't do `migrationsToDo = [migration_2015_01_02, ...]` and then just `map doMigrations migrationsToDo`? You don't need any sort of introspection; it doesn't seem you are doing anything interesting with the names, just calling the functions.

Comment: And adding them to a table of already-run migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to use the GHC API -- which is included in the ghc package (which is hidden) -- and is poorly documented.

I attach here a simple program which will print out the list of top level items exported in a module.  This should serve as a starting point.  This is a little command line utility which takes two arguments -- a module name and the word "class", "data", "function".  So, for example:

`test Prelude function`

will print a list of functions exported by the module (those that are not constructors or defined in a class).

In order to compile this (assuming it is in `test.hs`) you will need to do:

`ghc -package ghc test`

in order to make the GHC API packages available.

Here's the code:

```
import Data.List ( (\\) )
import Data.Maybe (fromJust, catMaybes)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

-- the GHC API stuff

import GHC
import GHC.Paths (libdir)
import ConLike ( ConLike(..) )
import Outputable (showPpr, showSDocUnqual)
import Var (tyVarName)

showU dfs = showSDocUnqual dfs . pprParenSymName

main = do
   (mn : ty : _) <- getArgs
   a <- runGhc (Just libdir) $ do 
     dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
     setSessionDynFlags dflags
     mm <- lookupModule (mkModuleName mn) Nothing
     mi <- fmap fromJust $ getModuleInfo mm
     res <- fmap catMaybes $ mapM lookupName (modInfoExports mi)
     return $ case ty of
       "class" -> [showU dflags c' | c@(ATyCon c') <- res, isClassTyCon c']
       "data" -> [showU dflags c' | c@(ATyCon c') <- res, (not . isClassTyCon) c']
       "function" -> let cf = map getName $ concat [(classMethods . fromJust . tyConClass_maybe) c' | c@(ATyCon c') <- res, isClassTyCon c']
                         df = map getName $ concat [ tyConDataCons c' | c@(ATyCon c') <- res, (not . isClassTyCon) c']
                         ff = [ getName c | c@(AnId{}) <- res] \\ cf
                         fd = [ getName c | c@(AConLike (RealDataCon{})) <- res] \\ df
                     in [showU dflags x | x <- ff ++ fd]
       _ -> ["need to specify: class, data, or function"]
  print a
```

The list of classes and defined data are pretty straightforward.  The list of defined functions includes functions defined in classes and constructors.  The above code, for functions, excludes these ( with `\\ cf` and `\\ df` ).

`a` is the generated list of function (or class or data) names.

The code which would invoke these functions would be the subject of a different question (and answer).

`lookupModule` is the function which loads the module for analysis.

The combination of `getModuleInfo` and `modInfoExports` get the list of "stuff" which includes the list of functions exported from the module.

The rest of the code is about getting those names in a usable form.